# Save Data URI as file using downloads.download() API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, download, data-uri, firefox-addon-webextensions

### Update

I have **solved this problem** (thanks to [**@DanielHerr**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3591628/daniel-herr)) by using a Blob URL / Object-URL (`URL.createObjectURL(blob)`), however I am still curious to why this error exists when using `data:` URLs

---

I am creating a extension using the WebExtensions API, for both Chrome and Firefox.

The extension gathers data over time, and I would like to implement a feature to export it as a CSV file.

I tried using [`downloads.download()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Downloads/download) to download the file, however I get the error:

> Error: Type error for parameter options (Error processing url: Error: Access denied for URL `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;base64,{data...}`) for downloads.download.

I have tried adding `"<all_urls>"` to the `permissions` key in the `manifest.json`, however that makes no difference whatsoever.

This is the code I am using:

```
var csv = 'Hello, World!' // Real data goes here
var url = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;base64,' +
           window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(csv)))

chrome.downloads.download({'url': url})
```

I cannot seem to work out how to resolve this issue, so I'll really appreciate the help! Thank you!

---

My `manifest.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Description",
    "icons": {
        "16": "/icons/icon-16.png",
        "32": "/icons/icon-32.png",
        "48": "/icons/icon-48.png",
        "64": "/icons/icon-64.png",
        "96": "/icons/icon-96.png"
    },
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "@name",
            "strict_min_version": "48.0"
        }
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["/scripts/a.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "downloads",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

`a.js` contains the code to export as a CSV.

I stripped the rest of the code down so that only `manifest.json`, `a.js` and the icon files are left, but it still reported the same error.

Comment: You could try a blob url.

Comment: Works for me, I can't reproduce. What's your manifest.json? Can you provide a [MCVE](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @wOxxOm Update the question to include my `manifest.json`. Did iyou test it on Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: In Chrome. I have no expertise on Firefox WebExtensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ah, okay. I think maybe only Firefox has this error.

Comment: @DanielHerr Thanks, it worked! Though I am still curious why the `data:` URL did not work.....

Comment: @Druzion Would you please stick to SO's Q&A format and post a self-answer with the code that helped you?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a Blob URL / Object-URL instead of a Data URI:

```
var csv = 'foo,bar,baz'
var blob = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"})

chrome.downloads.download({
    'url': URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    'filename': 'file.csv',
})
```

Comment: In Firefox, access checks for APIs such as `downloads.download` and `tabs.create` are stricter than in Chrome. At present, it is only possible to download/open pages if the extension is allowed to load the URL. In Firefox, data:-URLs inherit the principal from the caller (i.e. the origin), and out of caution that is blocked. But you could create a feature request if you think that access to `data:`-URLs is important (technically, Firefox could use a null principal to solve the concerns of leaking privileges). Here is the bug for opening tabs: https://bugzil.la/1269456

Comment: Blob based csv download is working in Firefox, i just replaced `chrome.downloads.download` with `browser.downloads.download`. Thank you so much for this answer, it saved me lot of time and trouble.

Comment: I stil get an error in firefox with blob url: `Error: Type error for parameter options (Error processing url: Error: Access denied for URL blob:https://stackoverflow.com/9544b599-ca83-44bc-859f-a9057e76ae1e) for downloads.download.`

Comment: Download dialog opens in chrome but file is not saved to disk.