# Function button to take a screenshot and download it as an image file

Tags: javascript, download, firefox-addon-webextensions, data-uri

I'm trying to develop a button that simply takes a screenshot of the current tab and downloads it (this may seem useless, as we can take screenshots manually, but I plan to extend the button's functionalities to make more things). I am using Firefox 116.0.1 (64-bit).

The code associated to the button is as follows:

```
function takeScreenshotAndSave() 
{
  browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab({ format: "png" })
    .then(screenshotUrl => {
      console.log("Screenshot URL:", screenshotUrl);
      const filename = `Capture-snapshot${Date.now()}-visible-1.png`;

      browser.downloads.download({
        url: screenshotUrl,
        filename: filename,
        conflictAction: "uniquify",
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error taking screenshot:", error);
    });
}
```

This works well until we reach the "browser.downloads.download" part, where I get an error:

```
Error taking screenshot: Error: Type error for parameter options (Error processing url: Error: Access denied for URL data:,) for downloads.download.
```

In my manifest.json file, I have the following permissions:

```
  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "activeTab",
    "downloads",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
```

So I have the "<all_urls>" permission, but this does not seem to be enough. I tried to follow the suggestions at [Save Data URI as file using downloads.download() API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269862/save-data-uri-as-file-using-downloads-download-api/) concerning the creation of a blob, but if I do that I end up with a file containing the "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABy0AAANzCAY ..." string, not the real .png file.

I'm stuck here. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I made your code works as follows:

Error: Permission '<all_urls>' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.

Solution: Site/URL permissions in ManifestV3 use a separate key: host_permissions

- manifest.json

  ```
    "host_permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],    
    "permissions": [  
        "notifications",
        "activeTab",
         "downloads"
     ],
  ```

Error in event handler: ReferenceError: browser is not defined at takeScreenshotAndSave

Solution:  In your function takeScreenshotAndSave() replace browser for chrome:

- background.js

  ```
    function takeScreenshotAndSave(){
      chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab({ format: "png" })
        .then(screenshotUrl => {
           console.log("Screenshot URL:", screenshotUrl);
           const filename = `Capture-snapshot${Date.now()}-visible-1.png`;
           chrome.downloads.download({
              url: screenshotUrl,
              filename: filename,
              conflictAction: "uniquify",
            });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error taking screenshot:", error);
    });
  ```

  }

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this does not work for me. I get "TypeError: chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(...) is undefined". If I use "browser" instead of "chrome", then I need to add the "<all_urls>" permission to be able to access those methods. But then I'm back to my initial problem. I'm with Firefox 116.0.1 (64-bit).

Comment: You should edit your initial question an add the info about that you are using Firefox 116.0.1 (64-bit).